# Mule - stop all flows from shutting down where MySQL connection in single flow fails

Tags: mysql, database, validation, connection, mule

I have a Mule application with a number of flows all performing various operations. One of these flows connects to an external MySQL database to retrieve information. If the connection to this database fails, my Mule application fails to start and none of my other, non-erroneous, flows start.

Is there a way I can configure Mule to revert to the exception strategy of the flow connecting to the external DB in the event that the connection fails or there is some other error so that all other flows will run as normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your global jdbc connector, set a reconnection strategy and configure the **blocking** attribute to **false**. Example:

```
<jdbc:connector name="mysql">
   <reconnect-forever blocking="false" />
</jdbc:connector>
```

This will stop the connection exceptions from blocking your Mule app and should allow you other flows that don't rely on the connector to work as normal.

More on reconnection strategies here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+Reconnection+Strategies

Comment: Thanks @Ryan. This has worked, although I get a recurring error and Mule tries to reconnect: `INFO  2014-03-26 11:22:41,355 [[processes].Mule.02] org.mule.retry.policies.SimpleRetryPolicy: Waiting for 2000ms before reconnecting. Failed attempt 14 of unlimited` - can this be limited to X retries or just default to my exception strategy?

Comment: Sure you can limit it using just the reconnect strategy:
<reconnect blocking="false" frequency="2000" count="2" />