# How to delpoy Mule application when Teradata, Oracle DB is down

Tags: oracle, mule, activemq-classic, teradata

If the DB or ActiveMQ, Teradata is down, service deployment is not happening. But code/service need to be deployed even DB is down. Kindly help in making corresponding code changes for this to make code deploy.

Comment: What you are trying to ask. make it clear

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Mule - stop all flows from shutting down where MySQL connection in single flow fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659111/mule-stop-all-flows-from-shutting-down-where-mysql-connection-in-single-flow-f): You can amend the reconnection strategy on the transport to not block startup if a connection fails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `blocking="false"` in your **JDBC** connector or **ActiveMQ** connector at the top that will allow ou to deploy or start your application even if the `DB/ActiveMQ` connection is lost or the `DB/ActiveMQ` is down.
With the current DB connector, you can implement it as the following example:-

```
<db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration" url="jdbc:teradata://<yourIP>/DBS_PORT=1025,USER=<your username>,PASSWORD=<your password>,CHARSET=UTF8,TMODE=ANSI" driverClassName="com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration">
   <reconnect-forever blocking="false" frequency="2000" />
</db:generic-config>
```

and in ActiveMQ connector as follows:-

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ">
    <reconnect-forever blocking="false" frequency="5000"/>
</jms:activemq-connector>
```